# счетчик неправильного входа JS

Tags: javascript

нужно написать счетчик для формы авторизации

```html
<html>
<script language="JavaScript">
function login()
{
var login=document.iAccInput.iName.value;
var password=document.iAccInput.iAccID.value;
var trueName='alex';
var truePassword='123';
if ((login==trueName) && (password==truePassword))
{
    document.location.href='http://youtube.com';
}
else
{
    alert("Error! Try again");
}
}
</script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
<center>
         <
 
<form name="iAccInput">
<table border="3" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" bordercolor="#808080" bordercolorlight="#808080" bordercolordark="#000000">
         <tr>
              <td align="RIGHT"><font size="3">Name
                      <br>Password</font></td>
              <td><input type="TEXT" name="iName" maxlength="15" size="20">
                      <br><input name="iAccID" maxlength="15" height="50" size="20"></td>
              <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" Login " onclick="login()" height="40" width="50"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</form> 
 </body>
</center>
</html>
```

нужно при вводе неправильных логина и пароля чтобы счетчик считал и когда наступает 3 ошибке блокировал вход

Comment: мне нужно это реализовать. помогите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let schet = 0;
schet = localStorage.getItem('schet');
if (schet > 3){
    document.getElementById('in').hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('vhod').innerText = "Вход заблокирован!!!";
    document.getElementById('vhod').style.color = "red";
}
function login()
{
    schet++;
    var login=document.iAccInput.iName.value;
    var password=document.iAccInput.iAccID.value;
    var trueName='alex';
    var truePassword='123';
    if (schet <= 3) {
        if ((login == trueName) && (password == truePassword)) {
            document.location.href = 'http://youtube.com';
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById('in').hidden = true;
        document.getElementById('vhod').innerText = "Вход заблокирован!!!";
        document.getElementById('vhod').style.color = "red";
    }
    console.log(schet);
    localStorage.setItem('schet', schet);
}
```

```html
<body>
<center>

    <form name="iAccInput">
        <table border="3" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" bordercolor="#808080" bordercolorlight="#808080" bordercolordark="#000000">
            <tr>
                <div id="vhod"></div>
                <td align="RIGHT"><font size="3">Name
                        <br>Password</font></td>
                <td><input type="TEXT" name="iName" maxlength="15" size="20">
                    <br><input name="iAccID" maxlength="15" height="50" size="20"></td>
                <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" Login " id="in" onclick="login()" height="40" width="50"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</center>
```

Comment: Я думаю стоит хранить это в localstorage. Иначе какой смысл, если после f5 можно снова пытаться перезайти

Comment: @Владислав Жидко, Хорошее замечание, спасибо. Добавил.